# How to make Visual Studio's View Designer act like Express Blend's View Designer like the screenshot below?

Tags: visual-studio, settings, expression-blend

Today when I opened a [Demo Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control), I found the VS was diferent from usual.
So which setting can make the Document Outline window act like this?

My environment:

```
VS2010 SP1
Blend4 SP1
Win7
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out by myself. This because I have installed Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview. It changed the default program to open vs solution file. So the pic shown above is not vs10, it's vs11!

Answer (score 0):

None that I know.  This functionality is specific to Expression Blend.

Comment: I've install Blend4. I wonder if there's some connection between these. Or if some one can give me a reason why this happened.

Comment: You're saying that visual studio actually looks like your screen shot?  That's totally weird.  I thought your picture was a mockup and you wanted VS to look like that.  It even looks like you're seeing the Blend design surface inside of VS (indicated by the golden exclamation mark on the design surface saying you need to rebuild).

Comment: So you got what I mean, the pic above is a real time screen shot. I was also shocked when my VS2010 suddenly transformed into something like Blend4 when I open the project file I mentioned above. Maybe you can give the [project file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control) a try if you have the same IDE as mine.